# Windows Batch scripting(splitting of strings using multiple delimiters)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a property file (test.properties) which has a variable which holds multiple strings.

Ex: var=str1;str2;str3;.....

I need to use the above properties file in my batch file (abc.bat), so that i could print the values line by line. Output of the batch file should look like this...


`str1`

`str2`

`str3`

`...`

`...`

(and so on)

Any help could be appreciated..Thanx:)

Ive tried to use "for loop" to seperate the values from first delimiter(=) in this way...

```
IF EXIST "test.properties"
(
    ECHO test.properties file found
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A IN (test.properties) DO
    (
        set value="%%B"
        ECHO !value!
    ) 
)
Output=str1;str2;str3;....
```

Now if i want to parse the strings in "!value!" line by line i use ...

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%x IN ("!value!") DO
(
    ECHO %%x
)
```

I am facing error.....Any help?

Comment: For clarity, always use the Code Block for pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a plain `for` to get elements of a list (`;` is a standard delimiter)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>test.properties echo var=str1;str2;str3;str4;str5;str6

IF EXIST "test.properties" (
    ECHO test.properties file found
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A IN (test.properties) DO (
        set "value=%%B"
        ECHO !value!
    ) 
    for %%x IN (!value!) DO echo %%x
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for the reply.....But if i use the same, it doesnot show any output , instead the variable "%value%" is null....That is the reason ive used "!value!" to print the strings

Comment: Ive even used "setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion "   at the beginning of my code